# Extracting coordinates from two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Say you have two numpy arrays one, call it `A = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]` which has all the x coordinates, then I have another array, call it `B = [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]`.. How would one "extract" a set of coordinates e.g (x1,y1) so that i could actually do something with it? Could I use a forloop or something similar? I can't seem to find any good examples, so if you could direct me or show me some I would be grateful.

Comment: to get a tuple `p` containing the first two elements of the arrays (x1,y1) you could use for instance `p=(A[0],B[0])`

Comment: @user2314737 Good answer! Why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: @ashbygeek because it's friday :)

Comment: @user2314737 Haha, ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concatenate multiple numpy arrays in one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517809/concatenate-multiple-numpy-arrays-in-one-array)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for. But you can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). You just have to add a *fake* dimension before with `[:,None]` :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

arr_2d = np.concatenate([a[:,None],b[:,None]], axis=1)
print arr_2d
# [[ 1  6] [ 2  7] [ 3  8] [ 4  9] [ 5 10]]
```

Once you have generated a 2D array you can just use `arr_2d[i]` to get the i-th set of coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

print(np.hstack([a[:, np.newaxis], b[:, np.newaxis]]))


[[ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 4  9]
 [ 5 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @user2314737 said in a comment, you could manually do it by simply grabbing the same element from each array like so:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

index = 2 #completely arbitrary index choice

#as individual values
pointA = a[index]
pointB = b[index]

#or in tuple form
point = (a[index], b[index])
```

If you need all of them converted to coordinate form, then @Nuageux's answer is probably better

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `x = np.array([ 0.48,  0.51, -0.43,  2.46, -0.91])` and `y = np.array([ 0.97, -1.07,  0.62, -0.92, -1.25])`

Then you can use the zip function

```
zip(x,y)
```

This will create a generator. Turn this generator into a list and turn the result into a numpy array

```
np.array(list(zip(x,y)))
```

the result will look like this

```
array([[ 0.48,  0.97],
       [ 0.51, -1.07],
       [-0.43,  0.62],
       [ 2.46, -0.92],
       [-0.91, -1.25]])
```